# Redirect user from mobile website to dedicated mobile app

Tags: android, iphone, objective-c, mobile, uiwebview

I'm wanting to give the user the option to view a more detailed version of a map on a contact page for a website. Is it possible on a mobile web site to redirect the user with a link to their dedicated map app on their smart phone?

Moreover is this possible for all / many apps on ones mobile phone to be directed to if they so wish, i.e gmail, dictionary, etc giving the user a better experience by merging mobile web and mobile applications? Would I need to use native languages such as java and objective-c to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible on a mobile web site to redirect the user with a link
>   to their dedicated map app on their smart phone?

For this, your mobile website, have to open an application on your smartphone, as question is tagged for Android, your website have to throw dedicated Intent which your Android based smartphone can understand as well as Intent should be registered as broadcast receiver for it.

But as far as i know, websites can have html/x-html format, by which email/call application of android can be called. I am not sure how x-html pages will re-direct intent to android system.